# Handling Spaces in Application.ExecutablePath

Tags: c#

I am getting a string variable for the Application.ExecutablePath and then passing the variable to a command line via ProcessStartInfo with some arguments.    My code works fine as long as the "ExecutablePath" does not contain spaces, but if it does such as C:\documents and settings\jsmith\desktop, C# processes the spaces as escapes and I don't get results from the command line.

Here is how I am getting the Path and also sending the command "lmutil"

```
string execName = Application.ExecutablePath;
FileInfo execFileInfo = new FileInfo(execName);
execPath = execFileInfo.DirectoryName;

string lmUtil = @"\lmutil";
lmExec = execPath + lmUtil;

This is the method in which I need to handle quotes in paths 

GetLicStats(lmExec + " lmstat -a -c " + licport + "@" + curAdd);
```

How can I make sure that lmExec is handled correctly if it contains spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
GetLicStats(lmExec + " lmstat -a -c " + licport + "@\"" + curAdd + "\"");
```

Put quotes around the address usually works

Answer (score 0):

```
execPath = execFileInfo.DirectoryName.Replace(" ", "\ ");
```

Just replace the spaces with an escaped space.

Comment: Thanks for the responses and your help in getting me to think in the right way about this. I ended up adding quotes around lmexec as shown:  GetLicStats("\"" + lmExec + "\"" + " lmstat -a -c " + licport + "@" + curAdd);